# CQRS: Return created ID

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I need to return the ID of the entity a command creates to the client.
(For example to redirect from `new-potato` to `potatoes/:id`)

I cannot create the ID on the client, for example because:

- The quality of client random ID cannot be ensured.
- Short, sequential IDs are required.

Can I return the ID when I submit the command?
For example the command is

```
{
  type: "CreatePotato",
  eyes: 3
}
```

the returned payload is

```
{
  data: {id: 1001}
}
```

and the event persisted is

```
{
  type: "PotatoCreated",
  id: 1001,
  eyes: 3
}
```

Comment: Short answer: yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can just send an ID with a command:

```
{
  id: 1001,
  type: "CreatePotato",
  eyes: 3
}
```

Since in a good system ids should be unique, immutable and never carry any semantic, then you can just generate some GUID, CUID or whatever you are using, right in the command, and assume that if command has succeded, your new entity ID is one that you have sent.

Comment: Yes, that is an approach that is often useful. But I gave at least two reasons why the ID cannot be generated on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I just started experimenting with putting the ID generation upon the construction of the command. By doing so, I can still keep a strict `(command) => void` signature in the command handler.

So in the controller, I'd do something like this

```
const postUserController = async (request, response) => {
  const command = new CreateNewUserCommand(request.email); // ID generation is done here
  await commandHandler.execute(command);
  return command.id
}
```